# Photoshop Script: Can't set "Save As PDF" options

Tags: pdf, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to save an Adobe Photoshop file as a PDF using extendscript. I want to set the PDF Compatibility to Acrobat 6 and encoding to zip. When I specify these settings, I am receiving errors as indicated in my script comments below. What am I doing wrong?

```
#target photoshop

if (documents.length > 0) {
    var saveOptions = new PDFSaveOptions();
  
    // This throws "PDFCompatibilityType is undefined" 
    saveOptions.PDFCompatibility = PDFCompatibilityType.PDF15; // Acrobat 6 or higher
  
    // These throw "Undefined is not an object" 
    saveOptions.PDFCompatibility = PDFSaveOptions.PDFCompatibilityType.PDF15; // Acrobat 6 or higher
    saveOptions.PDFCompatibility = saveOptions.PDFCompatibilityType.PDF15; // Acrobat 6 or higher
  
    // This throws "Enumerated Value Expected" 
    saveOptions.PDFCompatibility = 3; // Acrobat 6 or higher
  
    // Same problems with these settings
    // saveOptions.PDFStandard = PDFStandardType.NONE;
    // saveOptions.downSample = PDFResampleType.PDFBICUBIC;
    // saveOptions.encoding = PDFEncodingType.PDFZIP;

    // Save as PDF
    var f = new File( "~/Desktop/SAVE_TEST.pdf" );
    app.activeDocument.saveAs( f, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE );
}
```

Comment: where did you find a `PDFCompatibilityType` type? it doesn't exist in the documentation, it should be `PDFCompatibility`

Comment: `saveOptions.PDFCompatibility = PDFCompatibility.PDF15;` and `saveOptions.encoding = PDFEncoding.PDFZIP;`

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks. Strangely `PDFCompatibilityType` is an autocomplete option in the Adobe Extendscript Toolkit. It's also indicated here: https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/photoshop-latest/#PDFCompatibilityType.html#d1e29212

Comment: indesignjs.de is some random website ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ don't have ESTK so can't check. Anyway, it's better to check [the actual scripting references for your actual host app](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf): maybe there's this option in Indesign, but not in PS for sure.